# Drag thousands of dom elements with performance in mind

Tags: javascript, performance, dom

As a hobby project, I'm trying to create a prototype of a 64 * 64 tile based map that is draggable in a performant way. If this works, I would like to extend it to, say, 1024 x 1024 tiles.

*Current approach*
A "map" div that contains all the "tile" divs.
With [this jquery plugin](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/draggable-without-jquery-ui/) I make the map div draggable.
The tile divs have css sprite backgrounds so only a single call to the img is made.
This works good with a few tiles, but becomes really slow with more tiles.

*What I tried*
Thought to circumvent the dom reflow of all these tiles by putting them in a wrapper div in the hope it would be rendered in a separate layer and could then be moved as one. Didn't work.
Tried setting the map div's parent div overflow to hidden so redundant tiles wouldn't be rendered. Didn't work.
Tried removing dependency on jquery and do the draggable implementation myself. Worked equally bad. So didn't work.
Switching out the background image for a background colour doesn't improve performance, so that's not the problem.

*Ideas I don't know how to implement yet*
How can I make sure the tiles don't trigger reflow?
Would setting tiles that are out of sight be set to invisible? I can implement this with a bit of effort, but don't know if this would improve performance.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have a working sample online somewhere?

Comment: I can see if I can make one if I'm at my home computer.

Answer (score 1):

Render the group of tiles to a CANVAS element, export to PNG, then move that on drag.

Comment: That's a solution. It removes the possibility of animated tiles though .

Comment: @BorisCallens: You can animate the canvas, but you'll have to re-draw it for each frame.
David: isn't it possible to simply drag the canvas? Removes the need to save the canvas to a PNG, a relatively heavy function.

Comment: You certainly can drag the canvas. It's a little lighter to drag a PNG, depending on how often you "cache" to an image.

Comment: In an animation, that's usually at least 24 times a second. @BorisCallens'll have to see which of the 2 is faster.

Comment: Depends on the animation. Can you get away with an animated GIF/PNG? Does it really need so much detail while being dragged?

Comment: I can try both. If possible, I would like to avoid the canvas step however as it brings with it a whole new slew of problems like onclick on seperate tiles etc.
Also now that I'm on the 'use canvas' path, I might also check libraries like http://www.kineticjs.com.